# Python poetry not finding Python installation

Tags: python-poetry

I successfully installed Python poetry on my Windows 10 machine using the new script that will be needed from poetry 1.2.0 onwards (`(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/install-poetry.py -UseBasicParsing).Content | python -`)

However, when issuing `poetry --version`, I do get the message `Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.`

I am bit puzzled as I can easily call interactive Python via `python` (or `python3`, or `py`) from my Windows terminal.

If I deactivate `App Installer` in the `App Execution Aliases` settings and run `poetry --version` again, it throws an error stating that it cannot find `python3`.

What's wrong with my settings?